# I signed a lease with on site manager then the following day the owner of the property wanted to void the lease

Tags: rental-property, landlord, residential-lease, ownership, lease

I was approved to move into a lot,, so i paid a $100 deposit on a space rent and the onsite management made an  agreement with me to pay the remaining 435 by the 15th of the month. 24 hours later the owner wanted to void the lease until the 435 was paid. Instead of making me leave he refused me unit utilities and gave me intell 5pm on the 14th on the month to pay the 435. My lease states the agreement made with on-site manager?

Comment: What exactly is your legal question?  It's not quite clear.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on where this is and what kind of rental you're talking about, but generally, the owner has to live with the consequences of his agent's agreements. However, if you signed a lease that supports the owner's position over your understanding with the agent, the written document generally take precedence. On the third hand, your description makes it sound like the manager explicitly overrode the implications of the written lease (so on the fourth hand, it somewhat depends on whether he decides to support your position in court, or not – that is, can he maintain that you misinterpreted his statement? This is why the written document counts the most).

Your description in terms of "moving into a lot" doesn't match the tag "residential lease", which matters because a landlord can't cut off the utilities on a residential lease (apartment) under state law (if this is in the US), but the matter is not so clear for other kinds of leases, e.g. mobile homes.